# SpotFire: Set plot's marking programmatically

Tags: spotfire

I am trying to access the `data>marking` field of a spotfire plot programmatically.

I am trying to write a script that, when launched, sets the markings  for this plot to the values shown in the image below.

I m fine with using scripts, IP and button; I just couldn't find any example of scripts on the internet that access these parameters so I am looking for a short nudge to get me started.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the script below. It accepts a parameter named 'vis' which is the visual you're trying to set the marking for. In the example below "Marking2" is the name of the marking scheme.

```
from Spotfire.Dxp.Data import DataManager
from Spotfire.Dxp.Application.Visuals import VisualContent
myVis= vis.As[VisualContent]()
myVis.Data.MarkingReference=Application.Document.Data.Markings["Marking2"]
```

Comment: Oops... try adding this myVis.Data.Filterings.Add(Application.Document.Data.Markings["Marking2"])